# show Call to undefined function setActive() error in laravel 6.3

Tags: laravel

URL or Route `setActive()` method is not working in laravel 6.3. It shows the following error :

> Call to undefined function setActive()

Comment: I don't think this method exists in Laravel. Can you elaborate? Please share what you tried and what you want to do.

Comment: I want to set active a URL  when I am clicking on sidebar and i used below code                             <a href="{!! route('frontend.user.signin') !!}" {{ setActive('user.signin') }}><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Login as a User</span></a>

Comment: And from where did you get the `setActive` method? A package, a helper file? Does it was working before Laravel 6.3 (on the same project)?